# What is an alternative approach to large quantities of hidden fields?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, hidden-field

I am using 12 hidden-fields on a form to store some values that I need to persist along my AJAX posts to the server.

Is this a bad practice? Should I use another technique like storing a JSON string inside just one hidden field? Or it's common scenario having all this hidden fields?

Comment: Certainly an interesting question. It might be better suited to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Also, try to make your question specific and detailed. Over-generalised questions are highly opinionated and may not be very useful to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately there is nothing wrong with having 12 hidden fields on a form. It's hard to give advice on what you should do because I do not know your circumstances.

My only piece of advice in these situations is to evaluate the situation and examine what your application is doing and if there is a better way.

Ask yourself if a form is doing too much at once. Can it be divided up? Is there a way to simplify the task at hand?